# Represent interface generalization with lollipop notation in UML

Tags: interface, uml, extends, generalization

I'm not able to find any reference online on how to represent interface extension with lollipop notation in UML 2.0

I suppose is done like this:

[image]

But can anyone please confirm this?

Comment: I don't think so. You probably need rectangle notation since lolipops represent interface use/implementation (socket/lolli) but not the interface itself.

Comment: so I should use a class with the interface stereotype? @qwerty_so

Comment: Yes, I think that will be appropriate in any case and clear to the reader. IIRC (now) you can also use the ball icon for the stereotyped element. But for what you want to show that's not the way to go. Lollis are meant to show realized interfaces on classes/components as shortcut.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show relation between interfaces and classes in UML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64239374/how-to-show-relation-between-interfaces-and-classes-in-uml)  The title of that other question may mislead,  but it covers all the cases, including specialization of interfaces in lollipop notation and the differentce between specializing interafaces and realizing them.